# Each button plays a single audio piece

Tags: android

Being an absolute novice in android studio programming, trying to code three buttons, each of which will play a audio piece but they will not play all the audio pieces at the same time. Only a single piece can be played in a given time. The buttons are working and playing but the problem is that all the buttons play at the same if pressed.  Here is the copy of the MainActivity:

```
    package com.naomitan.multibuttonaudio;

    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;

     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        MediaPlayer mp1, mp2, mp3;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        public void firstButton(View view) {
        mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a);
        if(mp1.isPlaying() == true){
            mp1.pause();
        }else{
            mp1.start();
            mp2.pause();
            mp3.pause();

            if(mp2.isPlaying() == true){
                mp2.pause();
            }else{
                mp2.start();
                mp1.pause();
                mp3.pause();

                if(mp3.isPlaying() == true){
                    mp3.pause();
                }else{
                    mp3.start();
                    mp1.pause();
                    mp2.pause();
                }
            }
        }
        }

        public void secondButton(View view) {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.b);
        if(mp.isPlaying() == true){
            mp.pause();
        }else{
            mp.start();
        }
        }

        public void thirdButton(View view) {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.c);
        if(mp.isPlaying() == true){
            mp.pause();
        }else{
            mp.start();
        }
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your button functions, you have several mistakes as follows:

You are using `m` on both second and third button instead of `m2` and `m3` respectively.

Depending on the condition, you could be starting `m2` and `m3` on your first button

To fix that, simply do the same checks in all the button, each button checking whether it is playing (if yes, then pause, otherwise play) and whether the other two button is playing (if yes, then pause).

```
public void firstButton(View view) {
    mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a);

    if (mp1.isPlaying() == true) {
        mp1.pause();
    } else {
        mp1.start();

        if (mp2.isPlaying() == true) {
            mp2.pause();
        }

        if (mp3.isPlaying() == true) {
            mp3.pause();
        }
    }
}

public void secondButton(View view) {
    mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.b);

    if (mp2.isPlaying() == true) {
        mp2.pause();
    } else {
        mp1.start();

        if (mp1.isPlaying() == true) {
            mp1.pause();
        }

        if (mp3.isPlaying() == true) {
            mp3.pause();
        }
    }
}

public void thirdButton(View view) {
    mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.c);

    if (mp3.isPlaying() == true) {
        mp3.pause();
    } else {
        mp1.start();

        if (mp2.isPlaying() == true) {
            mp2.pause();
        }

        if (mp1.isPlaying() == true) {
            mp1.pause();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Heartfelt Thanks to you for your kind suggestion. I understood the way I made that silly mistake. I tried your given code. I was able to launch but if I click a button, the app's getting crashed. Please suggest.

Comment: Any crash message?

Comment: Where can I find such crash message? When I clicked a button, a message appears on the avd screen reading "App is not responding.."